# how to terminate the program when similar elements are found

Tags: python, list, python-3.8

I have the following 2D list:

```
test_list = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['I', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'B'], ['J', 'I', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
```

I want to compare the 1st list elements of the 2D array `test_list[0]` with all other lists. If the elements `['A', 'B', 'C']` are present in all other lists then it should print any message such as "All elements are similar" and the program should terminate when it finds the above condition

I have tried this piece of code but it only needs a termination condition: this is only a best-case scenario in which all elements are present.

```
test_list = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['I', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'B'], ['J', 'I', 'A', 'B', 'C']]

s = test_list[0]
for e in test_list[1:]:
    if all(v in e for v in s):
        print(e, "contains all elements of ", s)

#the program should terminate only if all the members are present.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another `all()` call to test all of `test_list[1:]`

```
s = test_list[0]
if all(all(v in e for v in s) for e in test_list[1:]):
    print("All elements are similar")
```